# No me quiere funcionar el decorador @input en angular

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular4, angular-directivas, angular2-template

Buenos dias al querer pasar datos del padre al hijo con el decorador @input al correr la pagina me sale esto en la pagina:

Failed to compile.

./src/app/hijo/hijo.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives' in 'C:\wamp64\www\prueba1\src\app\hijo'
 @ ./src/app/hijo/hijo.component.ts 13:19-67
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

talves me falta algo??  muchas gracias , estoy con angular cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el error dice que no se pudo encontrar el modulo "hijo.component.ts".

- asegurate de estar importando correctamente el decorador input de @angular/core de la siguiente manera:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core;
```

- asegurate de estar enviando los datos de forma correcta del componente padre al componente hijo asi:

```html
<mi-directvia [mi-variable]="mi-valor"></mi-directvia>
```

- asegurate de estar importando ambos componentes y agregarlos al array de "declarations" en el archivo app.module.js